# Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/content/30/10933330/html/sales/save_item.php on line 45

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, session

I have created a webstore in opencart. I added some extra pages for sellers to register and sell their products in it. When seller add a product it returns :

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/content/30/10933330/html/sales/save_item.php on line 45
```

and the product is not added to the main page.

My code is:

```
mysql_query("insert into oc_product (model,seller_id,quantity,price,image,status,listing_days) values ('$model','".$_SESSION['seller_id']."','$qnt','$price','data/no_image.jpg','1','$datetime')");
mysql_query("insert into seller_balance (seller_id,amount,remark) values('".$_SESSION['seller_id']."','$amount','$remark')");
$product_id=mysql_query("select product_id from oc_product where seller_id='".$_SESSION['seller_id']."' order by product_id desc");
$product_fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($product_id);
$product_id_result=$product_fetch['product_id'];
mysql_query("insert into oc_product_description (product_id,language_id,name,description) values ('$product_id_result','1','$name','$description')");
mysql_query("insert into oc_product_to_category (product_id,category_id) values('$product_id_result','$category')");
mysql_query("insert into oc_product_to_store (product_id,store_id) values('$product_id_result','0')");  
echo'
    <div id="div_after_save" style="float:left;">
<br/>
<br/>
<small><strong style="color:#000; font-size:12px;">Upload Image<br/>
<form action="send_hp.php" id="hp_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="h_pic" id="hp_upload" style="color:#000;" required="required" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id" value="'.$product_id_result.'"/>
    </form></strong></small>';

echo'<div id="image_div" style="width:300px; height:150px;">
</div>';

}
?>
```

pls help

Comment: Which line is "line 45"?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check your Query is right

Proper way to do this is

```
$query = mysql_query('Select * from table_name');

if( $query ) {
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) {

  }

} else {
  throw new My_Db_Exception('Database error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better idea, is to use mysql_insert_id()
Also might want to look into using prepared statements and MySQLI for your OpenCart, guides exist for this, but beyond the questions scope.

```
    mysql_query("insert into oc_product (model,seller_id,quantity,price,image,status,listing_days) values ('$model','".$_SESSION['seller_id']."','$qnt','$price','data/no_image.jpg','1','$datetime')");
$product_id_result = mysql_insert_id();
    mysql_query("insert into seller_balance (seller_id,amount,remark) values('".$_SESSION['seller_id']."','$amount','$remark')");

    mysql_query("insert into oc_product_description (product_id,language_id,name,description) values ('$product_id_result','1','$name','$description')");
    mysql_query("insert into oc_product_to_category (product_id,category_id) values('$product_id_result','$category')");
    mysql_query("insert into oc_product_to_store (product_id,store_id) values('$product_id_result','0')");  
    echo'
        <div id="div_after_save" style="float:left;">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <small><strong style="color:#000; font-size:12px;">Upload Image<br/>
    <form action="send_hp.php" id="hp_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="h_pic" id="hp_upload" style="color:#000;" required="required" />
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id" value="'.$product_id_result.'"/>
        </form></strong></small>';

    echo'<div id="image_div" style="width:300px; height:150px;">
    </div>';

    }
    ?>
```